# Apache struts internationalization and localization issue

Tags: java, apache, internationalization, struts, message

I am working on a `Struts-1` project which support two language `English` and `Turkies`. To display message we are using `Internationalization` feature of `Struts-1` hence we have two property file(`ApplicationResources_en.properties` and `ApplicationResources_en.propertie`s)  to store messages which need to be display to user.

For english version `ApplicationResources_en.properties` key and value is

```
farequoteautomatic.entry-area.gen.emd.fareamount=Fare Amount
```

For Turkies version `ApplicationResources_tr.properties` key and value is

```
farequoteautomatic.entry-area.gen.emd.fareamount=Ücret Miktarı
```

Everything is working fine when `Locale` is English means when we are using English version. There is correct and expected out put for that key which is `Fare Amount`.

But when `Locale` is changed means when we try try to use `turkey` version there no correct out put. It displays special chars rather than the actual char written in property fıle.

In property file message is `Ücret Miktarı` but out put at browser is `�cret Miktar�`.

Note: I have checked my Firefox browser is set default to `Unicede (UTF-8)` encoding and we have a `header.jsp` which is encluded in each page in which we have a META tag like `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. Please help me.

Comment: Just a guess is language pack for the other language installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed [mkyong url](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-internationalization-example/), It says.

`For UTF-8 or non-English characters, for example Chinese , you should encode it with native2ascii tool.`

With the help of `native2ascii tool`

```
farequoteautomatic.entry-area.gen.emd.fareamount=Ücret Miktarı
```

Converted to

```
farequoteautomatic.entry-area.gen.emd.fareamount=\ufeff\u00dccret Miktar\u0131
```

And at the browser i got desired out put that is `Ücret Miktarı`

Answer (score 1):

check your browser encoding and set it UTF-8

try this
in web.xml

```
<filter> 
<filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name> 
<filter-class>bt.gov.g2c.framework.common.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class> 
<init-param> 
<param-name>requestEncoding</param-name> 
<param-value>UTF-8</param-value> 
</init-param> 
</filter>
```

Comment: in the header.jsp we have a meta tag which sets encoding for every page <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: no check your browser encoding it is set UTF-8 or not.If it is chrome goto tools->Encoding

Comment: I am testing it with firefox and default encoding is set to UTF-8

Comment: Let me try it out. will be back soon with result.

Comment: I have added filter as you explained  <filter>
  <filter-name>Set Character Encoding</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.thy.gui.framework.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>encoding</param-name>
   <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </filter>
          But there no change in out put

Comment: here is doFiter method. public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
 { 
  HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
  //long startLong = (new SimpleDate()).getTimeInMillis();
  if (encoding != null){
      request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
  }
  chain.doFilter(request, response);
  //long endLong = (new SimpleDate()).getTimeInMillis();
  
 }

Comment: Make sure to put <%@ page contentType=”text/html;charset=UTF-8″ %>” in the first line of the view page.